# Angular calling function in child component from parent component

Tags: angular

I am getting error while calling function in parent component from child component. I think I am doing some mistake in child component while calling `func()` from parent

```
   parent component
    func(){...........}

    parent.html
    <child   (func)="func()"></child>

    child.component.ts
    @Output func = new EventEmitter();

someOtherFunc(){
    this.func.emit();
}
```

Comment: could you share what is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

*parent.component.html*

```
<child   (func)="func($event)"></child>
```

*child.component.ts*

```
@Output() func: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
someOtherFunc(){
    this.func.emit(null);
}
```